# JBehave and Java varargs - how to pass parameters to varargs method?

Tags: java, testing, bdd, variadic-functions, jbehave

I have a problem with connecting my method with JBehave framework. Namely, I have JBehave scenario like this:

```
Scenario: test1
Given all the data with attr1, attr2
```

Now in steps class I have a method with varargs because dependently on the situations i will use one or many parameters

```
@Given ("all the data from $attribute1, $attribute2")
    public void testinggg(String... attributes){

    int a = attributes.length;
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        System.out.println(attributes[i]);
    }
    }
```

Unfortunately I get an error:

```
Given all the data with attr1, attr2 (FAILED)
(org.jbehave.core.steps.ParameterConverters$ParameterConvertionFailed: No parameter converter for class [Ljava.lang.String;)
```

Is there workaround for this? How can I pass my parameters to  my testinggg(String... attributes) method?

Answer (score 1):

If you can control the separators between your attr strings (and you can arrange for them to appear at the end of the step candidate), then you can just pass them in as one long string, use split to convert to a String array, and then work with that array.

It worked perfectly for me in this example, where I could guarantee spaces as string element separators:

```
@Then("$tabbedPaneName tabs are $tabs")
public void testTabExistence(String tabbedPaneName, String tabs) {
    String[] tabsArray = tabs.split(" ");
programEntryScreen.tabbedPane(tabbedpaneName).requireTabTitles(tabsArray);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is JBehave's built-in [Parameter Converters](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parameter-converters.html) that convert to `List<T>` arguments, for supported types of `<T>`.  The caveat I've found when using this approach is that the converters require the delimiter between elements to be a comma(`,`) and *without any whitespace* around the delimiter.

The *Given* step definition in this setup:

```
Scenario: test1
Given all the data with attr1,attr2
!-- Note no spaces on either ^ side
```

Could be satisfied by this step-def method:

```java
@Given("all the data with $attrs")
public void givenAllTheData(List<String> attrs) {
   // do something, e.g. attrs.size()
}
```

One of the advantages of this approach is it supports multiple such parameters, and it is not limited to the last parameter in the method argument list (as with Java varargs).